# Where can I download the old Mavericks-compatible version of One Note?

Tags: macos, onenote

As of version 15.7.1, MS OneNote requires OSX 10.10: Yosemite. But company policy prevents me from upgrading to Yosemite.

Any idea how I can download an older version of OneNote that is still Mavericks Compatible?

Comment: This version is the commercial version to work with an outlook.com account - do you have a 365 version?